# What is a SAS disk and what cable does it use?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, sas

What kind of cable should I use to connect a [SAS disk](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0090UELTW) and [Intel® Server Board S2600CP4](http://ark.intel.com/products/56334/intel-server-board-s2600cp4)?

In the board specification it says:

> Integrated SAS Ports: 8

What are they? How to use them?

Comment: Its a SATA HDD. What is your question exactly?  It says so right on the label on the device itself

Comment: @Ramhound it says "SAS" not "SATA". They're different.

Comment: I just saw the question and it already has two downvotes. 
@OP: This is probably because the question did not show any research.

Comment: According manual this board has sata connectors not SAS, that's why the fellow is confused. Intel calls this SCU. See my reply below.

Answer (score 0):

SAS drives require a SAS connector.  It looks like SATA except the power and data are fused together in one connector.

You can plug SATA drives into a SAS controller but not the other way around.

If your motherboard has no SAS connector, you'll need to purchase an install a SAS PCIe card.

Comment: in the board specification i have : Integrated SAS Ports 8, so what are they ? how to use them ?

Comment: Sounds like your motherboard has 8 SAS ports.  You need SAS cables and SAS drives.

Answer (score -1):

> What kind of cable should I use to connect a SAS disk and Intel® Server Board S2600CP4?

According image of the motherboard and manual I have seen, in bios settings controller should be in SCU mode. This motherboard has SATA connectors instead of typical SAS 4 lane connector.

Google for cable like this: [StarTech.com 18in SAS 29 Pin to SATA Cable with LP4 Power - 18in SAS 29 pin to SATA Cable - 18in SFF 8482 to SATA](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71LvkRZfU2L._SX522_.jpg)

To connect it to backplane you would need reverse breakout cable.

Comment: Reply is taken from Intel manual. why down vote ?

Comment: music2myear - you have collected points by answering basic questions like "What is the purpose of the holes marked “Do Not Cover” on hard drives?" ... please don't discourage people from answering. I have provided him reply according the manual. Your attitude is offensive.

Answer (score -2):

SATA crossover cable with powersupply on it.

Comment: This information was already given. Please avoid posting answers that duplicate information already given.

Comment: No it's not given. it's crossover. difference is in wiring of SAS and SATA cables. You have problems reading ?

Comment: No, I don't, and this is a professional site where we request people discuss things professionally. The existing answers contain clear information that answers the question as it has been asked and provides context and helpful tips. They do not say that it IS a SATA cable, but that it "looks like SATA...".